# PC freezing about a minute or so after login

Tags: upgrade, do-release-upgrade, 19.04

Upgraded today from 18.10 to 19.04 and now every time I login my entire PC freezes. I can't open a tty or use REISUB. Unfortunately I didn't backup since my upgrade from 18.04 to 18.10 went smoothly when that released. Felt confident nothing would go wrong and took a gamble. :/

What can I do to recover from this and not be forced to do a fresh install?

Comment: As a first step, boot the live USB and backup your data!

Comment: Look at the logs! `journalctl --since "-20 minutes"`

Comment: I think it might be a problem with the 5.0 kernel. I'm using 4.18 right now and it's really sluggish but no crashing yet.

Comment: Here's what I caught before my PC froze and I had to reboot. Tracker-extract is eating up my CPU and RAM causing it to crash my PC. I only had Firefox and Tilix open when it froze up. I used 4.18 on reboot please ignore it. https://imgur.com/a/3oUSIRg

Comment: This is just absurd. Fully loaded RAM and swap. https://i.imgur.com/n306v3m.png I've disabled the tracker as a workaround in the meantime.